# Make a qml 2d flickable only scroll in one dimension at once

Tags: android, scroll, qml

To better understand the behavior I am looking for, look at google calendar on android:

[image: Calendar on android]

One can scroll downward to later times of the day. One can scroll left and right to different dates. But once one starts scrolling horizontal or vertical, one can not scroll in the other dimension without first stopping the current scroll.

How can I reproduce this behavior using a flickable in qml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flickableDirection` in combination with the `scrollingHorizontally` and `scrollingVertically` properties:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: contentItem.width
        contentHeight: contentItem.height
        flickableDirection: scrollingHorizontally
            ? Flickable.HorizontalFlick
            : (scrollingVertically ? Flickable.VerticalFlick : Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick)

        readonly property bool scrollingHorizontally: draggingHorizontally && !draggingVertically
        readonly property bool scrollingVertically: draggingVertically && !draggingHorizontally

        Text {
            text: "ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
            font.pixelSize: 60
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Idea of Mitch, I got the Idea of changing the flickableDirection when moving. So I added this:

```
Flickable {
    flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick
    onMovementStarted: {
        if (Math.abs(horizontalVelocity) > Math.abs(verticalVelocity) ) {
            flickableDirection = Flickable.HorizontalFlick;
        } else {
            flickableDirection = Flickable.VerticalFlick;
        }
    }
    onMovementEnded: {
        flickableDirection = Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick;
    }
}
```